# NodeJS - Store value globally from request header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to store the value from a request header and use it in several parts of my app. Which is the best way to accomplish this?

Here is an example on how I get the value (app.js)

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  global.exampleHeader = req.headers['example-header'];
});
```

And then use this value whenever I want in all my app.

For the example I use the global object which solves my issue, but I'm not sure if it's the best way of doing something like this. Any other suggestions or improvement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a really odd desire for a request header, but probably the easiest way is to create a module to store the data with setter/getter functions

Comment: Yes, you are right. However let me tell you how exactly this works: I have two apps that are functionally the same except for some styling. So I have this header that returns a value to distinguish between this two apps and apply the right styling/API calls to each app. I inherence this functionally and have to adapt to it. That's why I need this value available everywhere. Do you think the best way is to create a module to store the data? Thanks!

Comment: @BShaps where do you think the value should be stored in your solution?

Comment: If you have two individual apps my solution won't work if they might be used simultaneously.  Are these values meant to be global for the server or for each individual session?  If it is the latter, then you might want to check out [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) where you can easily store session specific variables.

Comment: The source code of both apps are the same, they just differ in details. And I need this global value (that came from an http header) to apply those details to one or another. So the values meant to be global for the server! @BShaps thanks for the answers! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> **res.locals**
>   An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is identical to app.locals.
>   This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

source: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought at this approach but there are some places that I have no access to res.locals :(
(Maybe I'm doing something wrong, of course)

Comment: ok, so is it the same issue in your case if you use app.locals? I see other scenarios depending on your needs like storing your global data in a database, memcache (redis...) or even sessions. But yes, you could also do a separate module which would be responsible of storing those values. I just do not see the point of re-creating a storage system when we have already a lot! :) Anyway, good luck and if you can share your final decision it could be nice !